# Why can't I select menus through selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="fancy-select" data-file=""><label>Choose a file</label>
<select>
  <option value="admin_20210519182831.log">SaveFiles\Logs\admin_20210519182831.log</option>
  <option value="admin_20210519183038.log">SaveFiles\Logs\admin_20210519183038.log</option>
  <option value="chat_20210519182831.log">SaveFiles\Logs\chat_20210519182831.log</option>
  <option value="chat_20210519183038.log">SaveFiles\Logs\chat_20210519183038.log</option>
</select>
```

my code

```
get_div = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('fancy-select'))
get_div.select_by_value("chat_20210519183038.log")
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Up\Desktop\New folder\test02.py", line 36, in <module>
    get_div = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('fancy-select'))
  File "C:\Users\Up\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 37, in __init__
    raise UnexpectedTagNameException(
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>
```

line 36

```
get_div = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('fancy-select'))
```

I have been stuck with this error for a long time, tried to figure out and try to fix it, but it didn't go through. Please help someone who knows help.

Answer (score 0):

See the error you are getting `UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>` all you need to do is to pass select tag locator.

You are targeting div in Select class. Select class from selenium only understand select tag. so changing your locator may work for you.

**XPATH :**

```
//lable[text()='Choose a file']/following-sibling::select
```

**Code  :**

```
get_div = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//lable[text()='Choose a file']/following-sibling::select"))
get_div.select_by_value("chat_20210519183038.log")
```

Comment: Why not "//div[@class='fancy-select']/select" ? Selecting according to class name should be better than according to element text.

Comment: @Prophet : here text is `Choose a file` so chances are very narrow that it will change. your locator is fine too but I assume there would probably be more than one class name `fancy-select`

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to give the select tag an id fancy-sel:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('fancy-sel'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('SaveFiles\Logs\chat_20210519183038.log')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('chat_20210519183038.log')
```

Comment: Don't mention `LOL` and `weird`  follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)